# Null data values in Formik fields throws warnings in the console log

Tags: reactjs, formik

I've started noticing in console log, multiple warnings for Formik fields where the data is null. see below..

```
    Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. 
Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). 
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

The reason data being null is due to the fact that these fields in the database are nullable and are optional in the front-end. I've seen a few suggestions on Stackoverflow where people put ternary operator ?:"" but doing so results in user input being overwritten each time when user moves on to the next field on the form.

e.g.

```
<Field
                        component={TextField}
                        label="Payment Method"
                        name="paymentMethod"
                        value={props.initialValues.paymentMethod? 
                               props.initialValues.paymentMethod : ""}
                        disabled
                        fullWidth={true}
                      />
```

For now the only workaround is in my API which interacts with MySQL DB. I use IFNULL() and return an empty string or 0 for null fields but I really don't like this approach.

```
IFNULL(pmethod.payment_method_name, '') as paymentMethod,
```

Any idea or suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Formik, it has props `values`. If `props` you are using in `value` is props of Formik, you can using `props.values` and `nullish coalescing operator` like this:

```
value={props.values.paymentMethod ?? ""}
```

Comment: Thanks Viet. The props here are the props passed on from one functional component to another. So, put it this way, I've a main functional component which contains a Formik form and it uses 3-4 sub functional components to render common elements e.g. address, phone, email etc as these form elements are used across my few other functional components, I didn't want to repeat the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Viet for your tip. I ended up using it in a different way. I am setting empty string values to the formik initialValues based on my API response. so, basically I use the coalescing operator on values returned by my API which populates my initialValues for Formik and this has resolved the issue. Also, now it makes sense as to why React throws warnings as it can't determine null or undefined values to re-render them.